# Konva 8.13, event click on shape doesn't work

Tags: javascript, konva

I am a beginner in Konva 8.13, and I am trying to do simple tools, where I have a panel with some shapes with a rec, circle, triangle, and so on, when the user clicks on an item from the tool, shows an alert message with the data about the object, with type, position, name. But the click-on shape doesn't work, I saw an example on the web, but without a success. The click works when I set the click event on the stage, but I can't know what object was clicked.

Code:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\web\View;
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="<?= Url::to('@web/js/konva/konva.min.js', true); ?>"></script>
    </head>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><?= Html::encode('NPI Layout Drawing Tools') ?></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <div id="container-tools"></div>

            <script>

                var width       = window.innerWidth;
                var height      = window.innerHeight;
                var tableCollor = 'lightskyblue';

                var stageTools = new Konva.Stage({
                    container: 'container-tools',
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    name: 'stageTools',
                });

                var layerTools = new Konva.Layer();
               
                
                //label
                var labelTable = new Konva.Label({
                    x: 1,
                    y: 1,
                });

                labelTable.add(
                    new Konva.Tag({
                    fill: 'white',
                    })
                );

                labelTable.add(
                    new Konva.Text({
                    text: 'BANCADAS',
                    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                    fontSize: 22,
                    //padding: 5,
                    fill: 'black',
                    })
                );

                layerTools.add(labelTable);

                //table horizontal
                var tableH = new Konva.Rect({
                    x: 10,
                    y: 30,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 25,
                    fill: tableCollor,
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    cornerRadius: 2,
                    id:'tableH',
                    visible: true,
                });

                stageTools.on('click',  (evt) => {
                    console.log('you clicked: ' + evt.target);
                });
                
                tableH.on('click', function (evt) {
                    console.log('Just a test');
                    alert('tableH: ' + tableH);
                }); 

                
                layerTools.add(tableH);

                //bancada vertical
                var tableV = new Konva.Rect({
                    x: 20,
                    y: 70,
                    width: 25,
                    height: 50,
                    fill: tableCollor,
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    cornerRadius: 2,
                    
                });
                layerTools.add(tableV);

                //Bancada hotizontal com jig
                var groupH = new Konva.Group({
                    x: 5,
                    y: 110,
                    draggable: false,
                });

                groupH.add(
                    new Konva.Rect({
                        x: 10,
                        y: 30,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 25,
                        fill: tableCollor,
                        stroke: 'black',
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        cornerRadius: 2,
                    })
                );

                groupH.add(
                    new Konva.Rect({
                        x: 18,
                        y: 36,
                        width: 11,
                        height: 11,
                        fill: 'orange',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        cornerRadius: 0,
                    })
                );

                groupH.add(
                    new Konva.Rect({
                        x: 42,
                        y: 36,
                        width: 11,
                        height: 11,
                        fill: 'orange',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        cornerRadius: 0,
                    })
                );

                layerTools.add(groupH);

                //Bancada vertical com jig
                var groupV = new Konva.Group({
                    x: 10,
                    y: 160,
                    draggable: false,
                });

                groupV.add(
                    new Konva.Rect({
                        x: 10,
                        y: 30,
                        width: 25,
                        height: 50,
                        fill: tableCollor,
                        stroke: 'black',
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        cornerRadius: 2,
                    })
                );

                groupV.add(
                    new Konva.Rect({
                        x: 18,
                        y: 36,
                        width: 11,
                        height: 11,
                        fill: 'orange',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        cornerRadius: 0,
                    })
                );

                groupV.add(
                    new Konva.Rect({
                        x: 18,
                        y: 58,
                        width: 11,
                        height: 11,
                        fill: 'orange',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        cornerRadius: 0,
                    })
                );

                layerTools.add(groupV);
                stageTools.add(layerTools);
                //alert(stageTools.toJSON());
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><?= Html::encode('NPI Gráfico do Layout') ?></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="container-draw"></div>

            <script>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem, the click event is working, but not above the object, but in the área next, how we can see on the image.

How I can do it?

[image]

Comment: I found out the cause of the problem, as I am using YII2 framework, when I called the screen using render directly, the problem occurs.